# PHP to extract specific .txt data from multiple folders and create a table

Tags: php, directory, extract, names

I have a project which I definitely am not capable.  I usually get a bunch of folders with approximately 17 files in it.  Each file has different variables I need to pull out and create a table with.  For example:

```
FOLDER: Server 01
TEXT FILE: password parameters.txt
PARAMETER: Password Length - 8
PARAMETER: Password Age - 120 days
PARAMETER: Password Complexity - enabled
TEXT FILE: audit settings.txt
PARAMETER: Auditing function 01 - on
PARAMETER: Auditing function 02 - disabled
PARAMETER: Auditing function 03 - enabled

FOLDER: Server 02
TEXT FILE: password parameters.txt
PARAMETER: Password Length - 8
PARAMETER: Password Age - 120 days
PARAMETER: Password Complexity - enabled
TEXT FILE: audit settings.txt
PARAMETER: Auditing function 01 - on
PARAMETER: Auditing function 02 - disabled
PARAMETER: Auditing function 03 - enabled
```

All of the .txt file names will always be the same and the variable names will always be the same.  I just want to pull out what comes after the '-'.  I need to create a table in which the first row would say 'Server Name' in A1, then the parameter heading in the following rows such as 'password length, password age, password complexity, and so on. Then in the second row, column A would be the server name, then the following columns would have the parameters I am looking to pull out.

With all the research done, I was able to pull the folder names but not able to create a table with the following code:

```
<?php
$path = 'C:\Documents and Settings\KK\Desktop\kk'; // '.' for current
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file)
{
    if($file->isDot()) continue;

    if($file->isDir())
    {
        print $file->getFilename() . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Then I finally figured out how to create the table, it pulls in all the sub- folder names as well as all the additional files in the folder.  I just figured that if this isn't addressed then the script will get confused when trying to extract additional files from the sub-folders.  Here is how I got there.

```
<?php 
// open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir("C:\Documents and Settings\KK\Desktop\kk");
// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}
// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);
//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");
// sort 'em
sort($dirArray);
// print 'em
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Server Name</TH><th>Other Info 01</th><th>Other Info 02</th></TR>\n");
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
        print("<TR><TD>$dirArray[$index]</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
?>
```

Any help you can provide in this area will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are closing your files before running your table, are you getting any number when you print the $indexCount?

Comment: Hello Shankar, the first example closes before running the table because every time I try to run it as a table, it keeps telling me its looking for an array.  I'm not sure how to do that.